# Lambda wkhtmltopdf Command not found

Tags: lambda, wkhtmltopdf

I want to convert html into pdf in AWS Lambda function. There is a node package that is using wkhtmltopdf. Here is its link.

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/wkhtmltopdf
```

But when I run my code I am getting following error.

```
Error: /bin/sh: wkhtmltopdf: command not found
at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/wkhtmltopdf/index.js:79:17)
at Socket.g (events.js:180:16)
at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:765:14)
at Socket.emit (events.js:92:17)
at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:427:10)
at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:423:5)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:166:9)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:128:10)
at Pipe.onread (net.js:529:21)
```

Is there anyway to install "wkhtmltopdf" command in lambda function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation (https://www.npmjs.com/package/wkhtmltopdf):

> First, you need to install the wkhtmltopdf command line tool on your system.

Here is a description on how to install files on lambda https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/running-executables-in-aws-lambda/

> Lambda’s built-in sandbox lets you safely run code written in any language, because Lambda doesn’t rely on the language runtime to provide isolation between functions. You get the same protections regardless of whether Lambda starts a process for you or whether you start it yourself, and regardless of the language in which it’s written. With that out of the way, let’s look at how easy it is:

and

> Including your own executables is easy; just package them in the ZIP file you upload, and then reference them (including the relative path within the ZIP file you created) when you call them from Node.js or from other processes that you’ve previously started. Ensure that you include the following at the start of your function code:

Comment: Thanks Vegahyo, I have integrated it

Answer (score 3):

I able to add the binaries in nodejs. Actually our code run at `/var/task` and it is in `process.env[‘LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT’]`.

So if we place binary at root in zip folder then we can include it in path like below.

```
process.env['PATH'] = process.env['PATH'] + ':' + process.env['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT'];
```